# saga fetch data after component rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

hi sorry for my bad english.i am using react and redux.i dispatch getTags action in  layout component.problem is after getData action called,getDataSuccess action called after my components rendered.so my data is null.
how i can be sure that data is fetched and render my components?

layout:

```
function DashboardLayout({
  children,
  showSideBar,
  backgroundColor,
  getTagsFromServer,
  getCategoriesFromServer,
}) {
  getTagsFromServer();
  getCategoriesFromServer();
  
  return (
    <StyledDashbordLayout>
      <NavBar />
      <SideBarDrawer />
      <Grid container className="container">
        {showSideBar && (
          <Grid item className="sidebar-section">
            <SideBar />
          </Grid>
        )}
        <Grid item className="content">
          {children}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </StyledDashbordLayout>
  );
}

DashboardLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  showSideBar: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  getTagsFromServer: PropTypes.func,
  getCategoriesFromServer: PropTypes.func,
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    getTagsFromServer: () => dispatch(getTags()),
    getCategoriesFromServer: () => dispatch(getCategories()),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(DashboardLayout);
```

saga:

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* uploadVideo({ file }) {
  try {
    const { data } = yield call(uploadVideoApi, { file });
    yield put(uploadFileSuccess(data));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(uploadFileFail(err));
  }
}
function* getTags() {
  const { data } = yield call(getTagsApi);
  console.log(data, 'app saga');
  yield put(getTagsSuccess(data));
}
function* getCategories() {
  const { data } = yield call(getTCategoriesApi);
  yield put(getCategoriesSuccess(data));
}
// Individual exports for testing
export default function* appSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(UPLOAD_VIDEO, uploadVideo);
  yield takeLatest(GET_TAGS, getTags);
  yield takeLatest(GET_CATEGORIES, getCategories);
}
```

this is my select box component which gets null data from store:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function UploadFileInfo({ tags, categories }) {
  return (
    <Paper square className={classes.paper}>
      <Tabs
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="disabled tabs example"
        classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator, root: classes.root }}
        value={tab}
      >
        <Tab
          label="مشخصات ویدیو"
          classes={{
            selected: classes.selected,
          }}
        />
        <Tab
          label="تنظیمات پیشرفته"
          classes={{
            selected: classes.selected,
          }}
        />
      </Tabs>
      {tab === 0 && (
        <Grid container className={classes.info}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} className={classes.formControl}>
            <label htmlFor="title" className={classes.label}>
              عنوان ویدیو
            </label>
            <input
              id="title"
              type="text"
              className={classes.input}
              onChange={e => setValue('title', e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={data.title}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} className={classes.formControl}>
            <SelectBox
              onChange={e => setValue('category', e.target.value)}
              value={data.category}
              label="دسته بندی"
              options={converItems(categories)}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.textAreaWrapper}>
            <label htmlFor="info" className={classes.label}>
              توضیحات
            </label>
            <TextField
              id="info"
              multiline
              rows={4}
              defaultValue={data.info}
              variant="outlined"
              classes={{ root: classes.textArea }}
              onChange={e => setValue('info', e.target.value)}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} className={classes.formControl}>
            <SelectBox
              onChange={e => {
                if (e.target.value.length > 5) {
                  console.log('hi');
                  setError(
                    'tags',
                    'تعداد تگ ها نمی تواند بیشتر از پنج عدد باشد',
                  );
                  return;
                }
                setValue('tags', e.target.value);
              }}
              value={data.tags}
              label="تگ ها"
              options={converItems(tags)}
              multiple
              onDelete={id => deleteTagHandler(id)}
              error={errors.tags}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )}
      {tab === 1 && 'دومی'}
      <Dump data={data} />
    </Paper>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  tags: makeSelectTags(),
  categories: makeSelectCategories(),
});


const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(UploadFileInfo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question Summary

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to guard the passing of options, `options={converItems(tags)}`, in the `SelectBox` in `UploadFileInfo` against `null` or `undefined` values when the data hasn't been fetch yet.

## Solutions

There are a few options for either guarding against `null` or `undefined` values.

Easiest is to provide a default fallback value for `tags`. Here I am making an assumption the `tags` are an array, but they can be anything, so please adjust to match your needs.

1. Inline when passed `options={converItems(tags || [])` or `options={converItems(tags ?? [])`
2. In the function signature `function UploadFileInfo({ tags = [], categories })`
3. As part of a fallback return value in `makeSelectTags`

Another common pattern is conditional rendering where `null` may be the initial redux state value, so you simply wait until it ***is not null*** to render your UI.

1. Early return null if no tags

   ```
   function UploadFileInfo({ tags, categories }) {
     if (!tags) return null;

     return (
       <Paper square className={classes.paper}>
         ...
   ```
2. Conditional render `SelectBox`

   ```
   {tags ? (
       <SelectBox
         ...
       />
     ) : null
   }
   ```

## Side Note about fetching data calls in `DashboardLayout`

When you place function invocations directly in the function body they ***will*** be invoked *any time* react decides to "render" the component to do any DOM diffing, etc..., pretty much any time `DashboardLayout` renders the data fetches are made, which could have unintended effects. For this reason, react functional component bodies are supposed to be pure functions without side effects. Place any data fetching calls in an effect hook that is called ***only once*** when the component mounts (or appropriate dependency if it needs to be called under other specific conditions).

```
useEffect(() => {
  getTagsFromServer();
  getCategoriesFromServer();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your functions to call the API inside React.useEffect.

All your API calls should be inside the `useEffect` hook.
For more on useEffect, read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
function DashboardLayout({
  children,
  showSideBar,
  backgroundColor,
  getTagsFromServer,
  getCategoriesFromServer,
}) {

  React.useEffect(() => {
     getTagsFromServer();
     getCategoriesFromServer();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <StyledDashbordLayout>
      <NavBar />
      <SideBarDrawer />
      <Grid container className="container">
        {showSideBar && (
          <Grid item className="sidebar-section">
            <SideBar />
          </Grid>
        )}
        <Grid item className="content">
          {children}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </StyledDashbordLayout>
  );
}
```